# How can I rename only specific folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def fileformat(path,file,mode):
    os.chdir(path)
    lis1=[]
    with open (file) as f:
        lis1=f.read().split('\n')
    print(lis1)
    fileslist=os.listdir(path)
    i=1
    for file in fileslist:
        if file not in lis1 and file.endswith(f".{mode}"):
            os.rename(f"{file}",f"{i}.{mode}")
            i=i+1
        else:
            if file not in lis1:
                os.rename(file,file.capitalize())
```

this function should only rename the file that are not named in a txt file. But it is also renaming those files that are named in the txt file.

Comment: Please make sure the indents are correct.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you should use `elif` instead of `else: if`

Comment: And if the list of files is large, you should use a set instead of list.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any extra whitespace in the file, or remove it using `str.strip()`.

Answer (score 0):

There might be extra whitespace in the file, so the filenames aren't matching. Try removing it.

```
lis1 = set(map(str.strip, f.read().splitlines()))
```